# I can't install .NET framework. System crash

Tags: windows-7, installation, crash, .net-framework

I ran into some trouble while trying to install .net framework. My laptop (sony vaio vgn cr41z if it matters) running on windows 7 x64, just shuts down during the installation process. No blue screen, no error message, no logout screen, no nothing. No errors even when I reboot. I had a look into this error log:

[image]

I searched stackoverflow for similar problems, but all I found was applications developed under various versions of .net crashing with the same error code (80131506). I tried to install .net 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5. Standalone installer, web installer, even via Windows Update. The same problem...

LE: I think this is a hardware or driver issue. I even changed the OS (Windows 8 Pro x64) and the problem wouldn't go. Good thing I have my desktop near. :)

Comment: Do you have anti-virus? It can be really picky about what access it gives to the .NET folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my computer was shutting down due to abnormal processor temperature. That's why I couldn't install .NET framework and some other programs. I solved this by going to Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> Change plan settings (on the active power plan) -> Change advanced power settings, and setting the Maximum processor state from 100% to 75% like this:

[image: solution print screen]

This worked for me.

Comment: ok, nice find. You should try to use Speedfan and increase the speed of our CPU fan.

Answer (score 1):

You get an internal error:

```
C:\Users\Andre>err 0x80131506
# for hex 0x80131506 / decimal -2146233082
  COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE                                          corerror.h
# An internal error happened in the Common Language Runtime's
# Execution Engine
  COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE                                          corerror.h
# 2 matches found for "0x80131506"
```

use the [.Net Clean Up tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) to kill every old .net entries. Now reboot and try to install .net 4.5 again (3.5 is part of Windows 7 and 4.0 is replaced by 4.5).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing .NET 1.1 and .NET 1.1 SP1 before trying to install. This is a relatively [documented](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=14&id=10658&Itemid=81) but the symptoms are very slightly different.

It's an older hack sir, but it checks out.

Comment: As you might already know, windows 7 comes with .net 3.5.1 already installed. Should I uninstall that one too ?

Comment: Personally I would get rid of every trace before moving forward and since you already tried something in between 3.5.1 and 4.x I would say at least try the service pack but you'll probably need to scrape it all out.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck... I managed to see for almost 1 second an error message (the exception at (some hexa number) couldn't read more) and then it went offline just like before... Installing 1.1 and 1.1 sp 1 won't do the trick, at least not for me.

Comment: In that case I am not sure :( Sorry I couldn't help.